# How to display a button on page after a period of time in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I want the button to display exactly 2 minutes after the page loads. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use javascript `setTimeout()` function to wait.

Comment: [Walkthrough: Using the ASP.NET Timer Control with Multiple UpdatePanel Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: if any of the below answers worked for you then just accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

```
        function showButton()
        {
            document.getElementById("btnContinue").style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        function hideButton()
        {
            document.getElementById("btnContinue").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        window.onload = function()
        {
            hideButton();
            setTimeout('showButton()', 12000);
        }

    </script>
```

</head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btnContinue" value="Continue" />
    </body>
</html>

Comment: <button id="MyButton" style="display:none">Hello</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

  setTimeout(function() { 
    document.getElementById("MyButton").style.display=' '; 
  }, 120000);


</script> as Craig said.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly is impossible, but close to is like this

```
<button id="MyButton" style="display:none">Hello</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

  setTimeout(function() { 
    document.getElementById("MyButton").style.visibility='visible'; 
  }, 120000);


</script>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("MyButton").style.visibility='visible'; ?

Comment: I changed it. Was doing it off the top of my head and usually use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can take jquery functions `delay` and `fadeIn` help for e.g

```
<button id="MyButton" style="display:none">Hello</button>
$().ready(function(){
   $('#MyButton').delay(500).fadeIn(400);
 });
```

`delay` will take an integer indicating the number of milliseconds to delay.

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5VANu/)

i can say its a workaround as it does what you asked for..

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to jquery. So I need to download it and then call it like this, right? <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> If that is right then it doesn't work. Does it matter if the <head> tag is on a master page and the button is on a different .aspx page?

Comment: put your jquery script tag in masterpage and write the above code in any of your aspx pages it will work, `head` tag mostly would be in master page if your using contentplaceholder for page

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery like this

```
<button id="btnButton" style="display:none">Your Button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
     setTimeout(function() { 
         $("#btnButton").show();
      }, 120000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to jquery.  So I need to download it and then call it like this, right?  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">  If that is right then it doesn't work.  Does it matter if the <head> tag is on a master page and the button is on a different .aspx page?

Comment: have you got JQuery.js file in your Application folder

Comment: It is there now, thanks for the introduction to jquery.  I have some learning to do...thanks again